# Can't run mysql inside container, which use dockerFile to build image

Tags: docker

I tried to build a mysql image with dockerFile.
Following is my code:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER jimmy

#install mysql
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev

#set permission of mysql
RUN service mysql stop
RUN usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

When I run **docker build -t mysql-test . --no-cache** it will build a image successfully.

But if I build a container and inside it, then run **service mysql start**, it will fail.

```
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld                     [fail]
```

I have to type **chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql** again, inside the container, so that **service mysql start** can be run successfully.

Why is that? I already **RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql** in dockerFile isn't it?

Comment: Why not pull a ready, functioning [MYSQL container from dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) instead of manually building it?

Comment: Cause I use this case as a docker training.

Comment: You can try with `sudo RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT Do you mean "RUN sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql"? I tried, but still don't work.

Comment: Just a try, add a line `User root` before the command `RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define `/var/lib/mysql` directory as a volume in `Dockerfile` -

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER jimmy

#install mysql
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev

RUN echo yes
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql        #change

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld   #change
RUN usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
RUN find /var/lib/mysql -type f -exec touch {} \;        #change
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld  #change
```

This Dockerfile worked for me to solve this issue. Docker recommends using a volume while you are using mysql service in docker.

Seems like it's still an open issue - https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/72

Ref - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35503

**Detailed explanation** -

> Yes, it's known that overlayfs only supports a subset of the POSIX
>   standard (also see docker/for-linux#72 (comment), thanks Akihiro)
>
> Generally, stateful data should not be stored in the container's
>   filesystem but in a volume. Not only does that allow you to upgrade
>   containers without loosing your data (which is even more relevant when
>   running those containers as part of a service, because updating a
>   service will replace containers with a new one), it also has a big
>   impact on performance, as writing in the container's filesystem will
>   add the overhead of copy-on-write filesystem that's used in
>   containers.
>
> See the "volumes" section in the documentation for more information;
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/, and the "Where to Store
>   Data" section of the official MySQL image on Docker Hub
>   https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/
>
> If your goal is to run a MySQL container, I would definitely recommend
>   looking at the official MySQL images, in which mysql is setup for
>   running in a container, and which also allow you to initialise new
>   instances from a backup using the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (see the
>   "Initializing a fresh instance" section in the MySQL readme on Docker
>   Hub)

Comment: Hello, I change the dockerFile like:
RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql    
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld 
RUN service mysql stop
RUN usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql 
but still can't run mysql, am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding a couple of steps previously. Updated the answer, try now.

Comment: Thanks man, it works! VOLUME seems a great way to solve this issue, I will learn deeper and then try the official image.

Comment: Yup. Maybe you can create a named volume & use it while creating the container instead of putting it in Dockerfile. You can go through Dockerfiles of official images to get good insights. Good luck!